# Rails - f.collection_select showing but not selecting the value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hello StackOverflow Users,
I am currently creating a search form,

and I would like to have a collection_select with the list of books available.

Users got books and an Join table is linking them

2 models : `User / Book`

A join table : `Book_User`
and a has many relationship for both sides

User Model :

```
has_many :games, :through => :book_users
  has_many :book_users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :books
```

Book Model
   has_many :users, :through => :book_users
   has_many :book_users
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :users

The form is working with a standard field the Text_field_tag and the results are correct (I need the book_name to make it work) :

```
<%= form_tag search_path, :class => "webdesigntuts-workshop", method: :get do %>
  .... 
 <%= label :book_name, "" %>
      <%# text_field_tag :book_name, params[:book_name], placeholder: 'books' %>
      <%= collection_select(:book, :book_name, Book.all, :id, :name, prompt: true) %>
      <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

The collection_Select is displaying the list of the books but when I select the name of the book , and click on the submit button ,the book is not taken into account in the request. I tried the option `:selected => params[book_name]` as well.

Is the collection select correctly written ?

I think i should do a f.collection_select , im in a form but i struggle with the attributes.
I hope somenone could help me on that part :)

Many thanks in advance,

Martin

Answer (score 0):

You must pass `book_id` to selected instead of `book_name`. Try it:

```
 <% book = Book.find_by name: params[:book_name] %>
 <%# text_field_tag :book_name, params[:book_name], placeholder: 'books' %>
 <%= collection_select(:book, :book_name, Book.all, :id, :name, {selected: book.try(:id)}, prompt: true) %>
```

Comment: It's working , I have no error but the selected value is not taken into account in the request. I will keep searching ;)

Comment: I got this as parameters in the console 'Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", ... , "book"=>{"book_name"=>"4"}, "commit"=>"Search"}  I guess it return an ID for the name and the search is expecting a string with the name of the book

Comment: If i can have this parameter "book_name"=>"bookTitle" it will work , i am close ;) , thanks for your answer btw